# Bucle bien reralizado?

Tags: php, wordpress, bucles, while

Estoy aprendiendo a realizar un theme de Wordpress y estoy en la parte donde se muestran los últimos posts.

Entre el **3º y el 4º posts quiero mostrar un anuncio** por lo que tengo que trabajar con el loop que muestra los posts de Wordpress.

He realizado este código y **me funciona perfectamente**, pero empiezo a dudar si el bucle esta bien realizado y el while puede acabar dando problemas...

En resumen, podéis echarle un ojo si controláis más de PHP que yo para **confirmarme que el bucle no está sin cerrar o el while es infinito**? Repito que funciona perfectamente, es por dejarlo bien hecho.

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <!--Entrada-->
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <!--Anuncio-->
        <?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 3 ) { ?>
           //mianuncio
        <?php } ?>
        <!--Anuncio-->
        <div class="card-body phome">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink($post);?>">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title();?></h2>
            </a>
            <?php 
                $sep = '';
                foreach ((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
                    echo $sep . '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . '"  class="cathome ' . $cat->slug . '" title="Ver todos los post de '. esc_attr($cat->name) . '">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a>';
                    $sep = ', ';
                }
            ?>
            <?php the_excerpt();?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <!--Entrada-->
    <!--Paginacion-->
    <div class="card-body">
       <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'paginacion');?>
    </div>
    <!--Paginacion-->
</div>
```

Gracias por adelantado ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo veo todo bien.

El loop lo haces [tal como se espera que lo hagas](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Using_the_Loop).

```
Abres un if en la línea 3.
    Abres también un un while en la línea 3.
        Abres un if en la línea 5.
        Cierras el if en la línea 7.
        Abres un for-each en la línea 15.
        Cierras el for-each en la línea 18.
    Cierras el while en la línea 22.
Cierras también el if en la línea 22.
```

Así que pinta bien.

Comment: Gracias por pararte a echarle un ojo.

Answer (score 0):

Si se ve bien amigo, en caso de que estés creando custom post type debes restaurar la  variable glogal $post, para que no afecte el bucle de consulta primario.

para eso usa esto después del bucle que hiciste:

wp_reset_postdata ()

Comment: Gracias por revisarlo también.